# CSS: Text area is not draggable

Tags: javascript, css, resize, textarea, drag

[text area is not draggable when enter less words or no words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JwJ6.png)

[text area is draggable only when enter words exceeds visible text area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXcEU.png)

css:
textarea {overflow: auto;}

It's not working when I add

```
resize: both;
```

or with !important

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: fix what? ... do you want the text are to be draggable or non-draggable

Comment: Change "draggable" to "resizable" if that is what you mean. Readers and answers may assume you are referring to the global [`draggable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable)attribute.

Comment: What browser are you using - risizing text areas works as expected in Edge and Firefox. Perhaps MS fixed some web kit idiocies in their version of the browser. It could be worth checking if it works any better with no value for "overflow" set in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this in HTML without CSS, and it will work -

`<textarea type = "text" draggable = "true" cols = "40" rows = "5"></textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <style>
        .textarea{
            resize: none;
        }
</style>
<textarea id="textarea" rows="10" cols="50" oninput="change()">Write something here</textarea>
<script>
    function change() {
        const dom = document.querySelector('#textarea');
        if (dom.value.length > 40) {
           dom.classList.remove('textarea')
        }else{
            dom.classList.add('textarea')
        }
    }
</script>
```